# How to make JQuery display hover image to the right of text (instead of below)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery code for a particular operation. When you move your cursor over text my code displays an icon.

I have a problem when I move cursor over the text, my image should appear to the right. Currently, it appears below the text.

Comment: I don't understand the code. Is the img inside the span? If you float the image it might show up where it's supposed to.

Comment: I think you're missing some code, I can't make anything out of that :P

Comment: I think this is missing some English. Between the excessive abbreviations and lack of grammar, this is largely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do would be to set the background-image and padding of the text with the jquery:

```
$(".pictureTrigger").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).attr('style', 'padding-left: 20px; background:url() top left no-repeat'); 
  }
);
```

check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mXDZc/1/), its a staring point for you, you'll need to do the mouseout if you want it to go too.

Comment: Because im nice i've included the mouse out code too: [http://jsfiddle.net/mXDZc/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/mXDZc/4/). Hope this works and its what you're looking for. Please accept the answer if it is.